# Get Ethereum Classic (ETC) transaction via web3 js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethereumclassic

For ETH, I get a transaction like this:

```
const trx = await this.web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
```

and everything ok. But now I want to get transaction by hash for ETC, and it doesn't work. It throws error:

```
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"Action not found.","id":4}
```

How can I get the transaction for ETC, help pls..
My config:

```
    mainnet: {
        provider: "https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet/api/eth-rpc",
        options: {
            chainId: 1,
            gasPrice: 20 * 1000000000,
            gasAmountToSend: 50 * 1000,
        },
    },
    testnet: {
        provider: "https://blockscout.com/etc/kotti/api/eth-rpc",
        options: {
            chainId: 1,
            gasAmountToSend: 50 * 1000,
        },
    },
    derivationPath: "m/44'/61'/0'/0",
    },
```

Comment: This is a question for BlockScout support which is a commercial product, as we cannot answer why BlockScout APIs work or do not work.

Comment: Yes, tnx. I try get ETC transaction without web3, with blockscout API and it works